# Can't get PyDev remote debugging to work with Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Everytime I start up Debug Server and try to add a breakpoint in my code, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydev/pydevd.py", line 711, in processNetCommand  
    breakpoint_id = int(breakpoint_id)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:    
'C:\\Users\blah\blah\\blah\\blah\\blah\\debugger.py'
```

I'm using PyDev Remote Debugging.

Comment: Try to paste the code in question!

Comment: It happens if I add a breakpoint at any line, doesn't matter the code, even if it's a blank line.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Java interface that provides the correct data to PyDevd has changed. The breakpoint id seems not be prepended anymore to the string that contains the file, line number, function and condition information.

I managed to make it work by changing the processNetCommand function in the pysrc/pydevd.py file.

I changed these lines (related to adding a breakpoint):

```
 710                     breakpoint_id, file, line, condition = text.split('\t', 3)
 711                     breakpoint_id = int(breakpoint_id)
```

into

```
 710                     file, line, condition = text.split('\t', 2)
 711                     breakpoint_id = seq
```

And these (needed for removing a breakpoint):

```
 753                     breakpoint_id, file = text.split('\t', 1)
 754                     breakpoint_id = int(breakpoint_id)
```

into

```
 753                     file = text.split('\t', 1)
 754                     breakpoint_id = seq
```

And afterwards I could happily debug again.